# Why derby connection closed after liquibase update?

Tags: java, spring-boot, derby, liquibase, bitronix

Here is the **Derby** `EmbeddedXADataSource` configuration for **Spring Boot Application** using **Bitronix** Transaction Manager

```
package org.chorke.init.entity.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BitronixConfiguration {

    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        PoolingDataSource dataSource = new PoolingDataSource();
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        dataSource.setUniqueName("java:jboss/datasources/CKDerby_initDS");
        dataSource.setClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource");
        dataSource.setAllowLocalTransactions(true);
        dataSource.getDriverProperties().setProperty("user", "chorke_init");
        dataSource.getDriverProperties().setProperty("password", "pa55w0rd");
        dataSource.getDriverProperties().setProperty("createDatabase", "create");
        dataSource.getDriverProperties().setProperty("databaseName", "/tmp/chorke_osuser/var/derby/init/chorke_init;shutdown=false");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**Liquibase** configuration for **Spring Boot Application**

```
################################################################################
# application.properties
################################################################################
liquibase.change-log=classpath:/META-INF/migrations/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.main.show-banner: false
spring.profiles.active: test
```

After launch the **Spring Boot Application**, **Liquibase** performed update operation successfully where either **Liquibase** or **Derby** itself shutting down the Derby connection as following:

```
INFO 11/15/17 10:55 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
INFO 11/15/17 10:55 PM: liquibase: Shutting down derby connection: jdbc:derby:/tmp/chorke_osuser/var/derby/init/chorke_init;shutdown=true
```

Causes application failure due to the Derby connection shutdown. Do you have any solution regarding to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
 <property name="shutdownEmbeddedDerby" value="false" dbms="derby"/>
```

To the changeset, this seems to prevent the shutdown when using Spring context.

See:

- https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog-property-substitution.html
- https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/database/core/DerbyDatabase.java